# Kubernetes Container application process recovery in case of Node failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In case of ec2 spot instances, if the node fails is there any way to migrate the running process of an application inside the docker container automatically to another node in the same state it was before the termination started?

Comment: If you need that type of behaviour from an application, it is a bad fit for both spot instances and kubernetes.

Comment: I read about an option **criu** or **docker checkpoint** is it possible to integrate it with kubernetes?

Comment: Docker containers mostly don't work this way at all.  It's extremely routine to stop and delete a container and then recreate it with similar configuration, and this is just the special case where you're recreating it on a different host.  Typically the contents of the container itself are disposable and if you lose the container it doesn't matter; you wouldn't generally try to migrate it.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes [doesn't support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3949) container migration.

Comment: Any chance ** AWS ECS** gives this feature? @Matt